# Multiple clicks slows down the application performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

***Before I explain the problem, I want to describe short what I am trying to achieve***

I have made 5 diagrams and one NavigationList. The NavigationList consists of pure HTML that displays a list of table1, table2, table3, table4 and table5 (JavaScript files). The user will click on a specific row inside the list, then the table the user wants to view will be displayed, and he can only view one diagram once a time.

*For instance: I the user wants too view diagram1, then he must click on diagram1. Later he wants to view diagram2, then diagram1 will be closed because he have clicked on diagram2.*

**The problem:**
If the user clicks multiple times on the same list name (for instance diagram1), then each click will slow down the diagram, very strange. So if the user clicks 10 times, the diagram will slow down 10 times more. Why is this happening and how can I solve this problem?**

This is **table2.js**, I believe that `$(document).ready(function()` has something to do with why the diagram slows down after each click.

```
(function table2(){          
  $(document).ready(function() {
      // table2 code content is taken away to save space in this file on stackoverflow... 
  });
}());
```

This is the part where I call the diagrams by using JQuery event with if statement.

```
    $('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
         var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
         $('.active').removeClass('active');
         $('#table' + row).addClass('active');    

         if(row == 1){
            $.getScript("table1.js", function(){}); 
            table1();
         } else if (row == 2) {
            $.getScript("table2.js", function(){}); 
            table2();
         } else if (row == 3) {
            $.getScript("table3.js", function(){}); 
            table3();  
         } else if (row == 4) {
            $.getScript("table4.js", function(){}); 
            table4();  
         }else if (row == 5) {
            $.getScript("table5.js", function(){}); 
            table5();  
         } else {

         }
    });
```

This is a statistic result that shows why the performance is so slow, as you can see; each table is receiving data samples. After multiple clicks the performance is high drops down from 40 fps to 6.5 fps, strange?? 
[Click here to view the slow performance statistics](http://gyazo.com/84a9ba1cee92273b05d8001a5dfdd0fb)

Comment: You should use a `switch` statement instead of multiple `if else` statements.

Comment: ... and you shouldn't involve `$.getScript()` in interactive callbacks at all.

Comment: @Psioniax, good idea. I will implement this later on. But this does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Pointy, what should I involve then? Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

because each click you doing ajax request so if you click 10 times you making 10 requests plus calling  table12();  functions which can be heavy.. you need to change your code to check if diagram is visible if yes dont do another request

Comment: How can I check if the diagram is visible or not?

Comment: `$('selector').is(':visible');`

Comment: Shall I just add this below 
`$('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
                 var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
                 $('.active').removeClass('active');
                 $('#table' + row).addClass('active');`

Comment: I found it hard to understand your question... I would be glad if you could put it in context.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a memory leak. Make sure you clean up global variables properly and DOM nodes properly. Your browser should have developer tools which should allow you to see memory usage.

I'm also a bit worried by this code:

```
$.getScript("SensorTables/ExhaustTemperature.js", function(){}); 
table1();
```

`.getScript()` is an asynchronous function, so `table1()` will be executed *before* the browser has loaded the script.

The correct code is probably:

```
$.getScript("table1.js", function(){});
```

since the function `table1` is defined in such a way that it's executed right away. That means your code logs an error in the JavaScript console when you click the first time. When you click a second time, the function is called twice (once when jQuery fetches the script from the server and again from your code).

`$(document).ready();` isn't necessary inside of `(function table1(){}());` - when this code is executed, the DOM is ready. Maybe the code is there because other pages use the script as well. My recommendation would be to move that into the places where you need it.

Lastly, if you give the function a name, then the browser keeps it around. That may eat a lot of memory, depending on how complex the code is. If you want to keep the code around, this should be much faster:

```
if(table1) {
    table1();
} else {
    $.getScript("table1.js");
}
```

since it loads the script only once.

If you want to load the script again every time the user clicks and save memory:

```
$.getScript("table1.js");
```

and change the script to

```
(function (){          
  // table2 code content is taken away to save space in this file on stackoverflow... 
}());
```

(i.e. remove the name of the function). The browser will then execute it once and forget as much as it can about it.

Comment: I am also worried about that part, is there any other options I could think about or use?

Comment: Yes, there are many options that you can use. Maybe you can tell me more about specific problems that you have :-) That way, I could give you more specific answers.

Comment: @DlerHasan Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you may be able to replace `function(){}` with `table1`

Comment: @S.Buda, Do you mean like this: `$.getScript("table1.js", table1());`, because this does not work.

Comment: @DlerHasan, you would want to remove the parenthesis after `table1` as you would want to give it the name of the function rather than calling the function it's self.

Comment: @S.Buda, isn't this the table1 the name of the function? It is from `(function table2(){`....

Comment: This is what I have done step 1: 
`(function (){          
  // table1 code content is taken away to save space in this file on stackoverflow... 
}());`

Then step 2:
`if(row == 1){
                    $.getScript("table1.js"); 
                 }`

Result: Diagram displays, but if I click multiple times, the same problem as above happens, the diagram slows down..

Comment: That means you now have to look at the code inside of `table1.js`.